# ¿como implementar un método a este ejercicio?

Tags: java

Llevo haciendo este código hace un par de días y me hace falta implementarlo en un método,llevo varias horas tratando de terminarlo y no he podido

```
public class MayorPar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] x = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Elemento [" + i + "]");
            x[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Elemento [" + i + "]: " + x[i]);
        }

        Mayores(x);
        sc.close();
    }

    public static void Mayores(int[] x) {
        int mayor = Integer.MIN_VALUE, indice = 0, mayorPar = Integer.MIN_VALUE, indiceMayorPar = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (x[i] > mayor) {
                mayor = x[i];
                indice = i;
            }
            if (x[i] % 2 == 0 && x[i] > mayorPar) {
                mayorPar = x[i];
                indiceMayorPar = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("El número mayor par es: " + mayorPar + " y su posición es: " + indiceMayorPar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema con este codigo?

Comment: Hola @Jose Arrieta, No se entiende tu pregunta y que es lo que necesitas, por favor agrega mas información y especifica que necesitas crear como metodo?

Comment: Hola, no se entiende bien la pregunta, que es lo que necesitas pasar a un metodo? lo que esta en el main?

Comment: Haber, el código funciona perfecto , pero debo implementarlo en un método y para eso  tengo que pasarle el array... eso es l oque necesito.

Comment: me pueden colaborar explicándome como? se los agradecería!

Comment: Lo que yo veo es: Una clase con su método `main`, y un método adicional que ya recibe un array por parámetro. No te funciona el método?

Comment: si funciona pero  quisiera implementar el array en una clase aparte

Comment: He revertido la última edición del OP, pues al quitar el código la pregunta pierde aún más el sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!Buenas!

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, quieres realizar un método para cada parte de tu código...

He hecho una clase llamada **MayorPar** y he creado los métodos necesarios (desde mi punto de vista) que vas a necesitar y los que ya has creado tu mismo. Después solo tienes que crear la instancia en la clase **main**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MayorPar {

```
private int mayor;
private int indice;
private int mayorPar;
private int indiceMayorPar;
private int[] x ;

public MayorPar() {

    mayor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    indice = 0;
    mayorPar = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    indiceMayorPar = 0;
    x = new int[3];

}

public void Mayores(int[] x) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (x[i] > mayor) {
            mayor = x[i];
            indice = i;
        }

        if (x[i] % 2 == 0 && x[i] > mayorPar) {
            mayorPar = x[i];
            indiceMayorPar = i;
        }
    }

}

public void pedirElemento() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("introduce el elemento [" + i + "]: ");
        x[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Elemento [" + i + "]: " + x[i]);
    }
}

public String toString() {

    return "El número mayor par es: " + mayorPar + " y su posición es: " + indiceMayorPar;
}

public int[] getX() {
    return x;
}
```

}

Aquí te dejo la clase main:

```
public class TestMayor {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MayorPar test = new MayorPar();

    test.pedirElemento();
    test.Mayores(test.getX());

    System.out.println(test.toString());

}
```

}

Por favor si esto no resuelve tu duda, plantea mejor el enunciado. !Un saludo!

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS HERMANO!!!  era exactamente lo que necesitaba, te lo agradezco, por cierto, ¿ podrías ayudarme con la siguiente pregunta que publique?

Comment: Si te ha servido !por favor dale reputación! Gracias :D